# Testing that a method in instance has been called in mock

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, mocking

I have this sort of setup where I'm testing a class which is using another class, and I want to mock the latter so I'm only testing the first class itself.

`nuclear_reactor.py`:

```
class NuclearReactor():
    def __init__(self):
        print "initializing the nuclear reactor"

    def start(self):
        print "starting the nuclear reactor"
```

`nuclear_manager.py`:

```
from nuclear_reactor import NuclearReactor

class NuclearManager():
    def __init__(self):
        print "manager creating the nuclear reactor"
        self.reactor = NuclearReactor()

    def start(self):
        print "manager starting the nuclear reactor"
        self.reactor.start()
```

`test_nuclear_manager.py`:

```
from mock import Mock
import nuclear_manager
from nuclear_manager import NuclearManager

def test():
    mock_reactor = nuclear_manager.NuclearReactor = Mock()
    nuke = NuclearManager()
    nuke.start()
    nuke.start()
    print mock_reactor.mock_calls
    print mock_reactor.start.call_count

test()
```

What I'd like to test is that `NuclearReactor.start` is called,
but when I run this I get:

```
manager creating the nuclear reactor
manager starting the nuclear reactor
manager starting the nuclear reactor
[call(), call().start(), call().start()]
0
```

Which I totally understand since `start` is an attribute of the instance and not of the class, and I could parse the `mock_calls`, but isn't there a better way to check that the call of an instantiated mocked class is made?

I could use dependency injection in `NuclearManager` to pass a mock `NuclearReactor`, but I'm thinking there would be an alternative way using just mock.

Comment: Why do you expect `.start()` to be called once when you call the manager twice?

Comment: Yes, you should inject an instance into `NuclearManager` because your code now makes the manager set its `reactor` instance to a default value. Only the highest level parts of a program should have defaults.

Comment: @quamrana: whether or not the OP should use dependency injection is an entirely separate discussion. Not all code under test will be suitable for dependency injection.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are indeed testing if `start` has been called *directly on the class*, which your code does not. You can test the method on the instance directly; remember that an instance is produced by calling the class:

```
print mock_reactor.return_value.calls
print mock_reactor.return_value.start.call_count
```

The [`Mock.return_value` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.return_value) is the result of the call to the mocked class, so the instance.

You can also just *call* the mock. Mocks by default always return the exact same object when called, a new mock representing that return value:

```
print mock_reactor().calls
print mock_reactor().start.call_count
```

The result of calling a mock instance, and the mock instance `return_value` attribute, are one and the same.

You were already on the right path by printing out the calls to the `NuclearReactor` mock, you just missed the detail that `start()` was invoked on the *called* mock, so `call().start()`, not `start()` was recorded.

You may want to use [`mock.patch()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) to handle the patching, rather than by direct assignment; this makes sure that the patch is *removed* again so that other tests can make their own decisions on what is mocked:

```
import mock
from nuclear_manager import NuclearManager

@mock.patch('nuclear_manager.NuclearReactor')
def test(mock_reactor):
    nuke = NuclearManager()
    nuke.start()
    nuke.start()

    instance = mock_reactor.return_value
    assert instance.start.call_count == 2
    instance.assert_called()
```

I used it as a decorator here; when the `test()` function is called, the mock is put in place, and when the function exits, it is removed again. You can also use `patch()` as a context manager to limit the scope of the patch even more finely.

Also, for unit testing like this, do use the [`unittest` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html):

```
import mock
import unittest
import nuclear_manager

class NuclearManagerTests(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('nuclear_manager.NuclearReactor')
    def test_start(self, mock_reactor):
        nuke = NuclearManager()
        nuke.start()
        nuke.start()

        instance = mock_reactor.return_value
        self.assertEqual(instance.start.call_count, 2)
        instance.assert_called()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

This lets you fit your tests into a larger test suite, enable and disable tests, and integrate with other testing tools.

Comment: Not that I use `patch` myself, but its good to know that `@patch()` will restore the scope later.

Comment: Thanks a lot Marijn, makes sense. Just a note that I'm using `pytest` so no need for the `unittest` extra baggage. The `assert` is all I need.

Answer (score -2):

The way I use mocks is like this: (Code is Python 3)

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

class NuclearManager():
    def __init__(self, reactor):
        print("manager creating the nuclear reactor")
        self.reactor = reactor

    def start(self):
        print("manager starting the nuclear reactor")
        self.reactor.start()


def test():
    mock_reactor = MagicMock()
    nuke = NuclearManager(mock_reactor)
    nuke.start()
    nuke.start()

    # These two prints would actually be asserts of some sort
    print(mock_reactor.mock_calls)
    print(mock_reactor.start.call_count)

test()
```

Output:

```
manager creating the nuclear reactor
manager starting the nuclear reactor
manager starting the nuclear reactor
[call.start(), call.start()]
2
```

Comment: The OP has a hypothetical situation. Not all code requires injection, you can trivially still reach the instance, because that's a **call** to the class.