# How do I assert that a mocked class method was called with pytest?

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

```
# blah app
class MyClass():
    def some_method():
        pass

# some_app app
from blah.service import MyClass
def some_app_function()
    my_class = MyClass()
    my_class.some_method()


@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_class_method_called(mocker):
    my_class = mocker.patch('some_app.MyClass')
    service.some_app_function()
    assert my_class.some_method.called # Getting False
```

I've done the exact same thing for functions and it works but `called` is not `True` when it's a method in class.  What am I missing?

Comment: Just *call the method*, you don't need assert rewriting here. Otherwise you're asserting that the method evaluates truthy, which it always will.

Comment: I want to ensure that `my_class.some_function` was called when `some_app_function` is called.  I obviously gave a simple example here but my actual dictates that I assert for this.

Comment: That's not actually Python syntax, so it's hard to tell exactly what your problem is. But [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) show you how to call the various mock assertion methods.

Comment: I initialized the object incorrectly, I guess that may have been unintuitive?  Was there something else?

Comment: I have to do my_class().some_method.called ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47606924/1078232

Answer (score 0):

The name you want to patch is from the same module as `some_app_function`; you are patching the wrong name.

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_class_method(mocker):
    my_class = mocker.patch('service.MyClass')
    sevice.some_app_function()
    assert my_class.some_function.called
```

Comment: agh... I was doing that and it still doesn't work.  I'll fix the question.  I did see that I have a MagicMock object if I print `my_class.some_function`